# "Module not found error" when trying to run pytube on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytube

I am trying to use pytube to download videos but it isn't working. I don't know much about python (or any other programming language) so it is likely that my problem is easy to solve. I have tried reading multiple websites and watching several YouTube videos, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

- I use a MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6;
- I have both Python 2.7.16 and Python 3.8.3 versions installed;
- I used the terminal to install pytube using "pip install pytube3";
- When I try to install again using the same command as above, I think that it is correctly installed, because the terminal shows the following messages:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytube3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (9.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pytube3) (3.7.4.3)
```

- I am trying to use PyCharm 2020.2.1 (Community Edition)
- I think that pytube is also OK in PyCharm, because it appears in "External libraries" under "site-packages"

**My problem:**
When I open PyCharm, it opens on "main.py". There, I try to write:

`import pytube.`

But I get the following message:

```
/Users/applemacosx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/venv/bin/python /Users/applemacosx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/applemacosx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried searching about this error, but I wasn't able to find anything that I could make work. I would be very grateful if someone could help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: because you installed the pytube in python environment. buy your pycharm is using one venv environment. so try to install the package inside the venv..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you've indeed installed `pytube` on the python installation on your machine, but Pycharm *creates a virtual environment for each new project you create*.

So while `pytube` is installed in the python environment on your machine, it's not installed in this newly created python environment. The solution is to install `pytube` in the project's virtual environment. There a couple of ways to do that. Probably the easiest would be to go to the terminal window in Pycharm, and execute the `pip` install command.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening due to virtual environment, which PyCharm creates separately for each and every project. There are many ways to add a library to current project but the easiest way could be to add directly from PyCharm.

**Steps:**

1. Go to Top left, click on `PyCharm`
2. Then click on `Preferences`
3. Now, In the preferences search for `Project Interpreter`
4. After this click on `+` sign to add `pytube`
5. Once you click on `+`, you would see another pop up window, you need to put `putube` there and select the exact match or the one you are looking for(You can mention the version too).
6. At last click on `Install package`. `pytube` will be install in few seconds and you can start importing in your module.

The below screenshots could help you more:

[image]

[image]